# Right-side Menu Not Working

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I was hoping to pick your brains about why my right-side menu won’t open. It used to but after I’ve been fiddling about adding scrolling lightboxes it’s not any more. I am unable to identify if this is a html / css / js problem as have tried to revert to previously used html / css and js when the menu does pop-up and this hasn't resolved. I have also tried cleaning up the HTML and CSS and neither has worked so I have reverted back to what I find tidier working with.

This particular site is for fun and is adapted from HTML5UP's examples, for which this particular site is available here: [HTML5 UP Phantom](https://html5up.net/phantom) with a working menu - which is how mine was prior to adding in the lightboxes.

I will attempt to include my code and css and would be very grateful for any ideas about what has gone wrong. I have tried to include a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kch2hqLf/2/) but cannot see how to add multiple different javascripts in - but would be happy to if someone can let me know how to do this! I am wondering if this is a problem of the new JS scripts I've added conflicting with those that the menu would use.

```
            <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <div class="inner">

                        <!-- Logo -->
                            <a href="index.dwt" class="logo">
                                <span class="symbol"><img src="../images/logo1.jpg" alt="" /></span><span class="title">Single in Brisbane</span>
                            </a>

                        <!-- Nav -->
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>

                    </div>
                </header>

            <!-- Menu -->
                <nav id="menu">
                    <h2>Menu</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.dwt">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../SubPage1.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../Subscribe.html">Subscribe</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../SubPage1.html">Giveaways</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../SubPage1.html">Advertise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Of note, I have just noticed that when in preview in browser mode (I use Google Chrome) instead of opening the menu (as it does in the original downloaded site) it instead adds a #menu at the end of the web address. 

So: 
---file://macintosh%20hd/Users/S/Documents/Adobe%20InDesign%20Site%20Folder/SingleInBrisbane/Website/Single%20in%20Brisbane/Templates/index.dwt---

Becomes: 
---file://macintosh%20hd/Users/S/Documents/Adobe%20InDesign%20Site%20Folder/SingleInBrisbane/Website/Single%20in%20Brisbane/Templates/index.dwt#menu---

Seems to be pointing to correct CSS though?